# How to add a different line to the beginning of each line of a file

Tags: file, variables, loops, unix, addition

I have a file that looks like this:

```
coffee
soda
pizza
hamburger
fries
```

I want to add a line to the beginning of these lines so that it'll give me this:

```
Enter 1 for: coffee
Enter 2 for: soda
Enter 3 for: pizza
Enter 4 for: hamburger
Enter 5 for: fries
```

How should I do this? I am guessing that I should use a loop, but don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i had to do this, i'd use

```
grep -n ^ file |                         # prepend the line number and a : to each line
sed 's/^\([0-9]*\):/Enter \1 for:/'      # surround the line number with the text you need
```

The trick with grep is that `^` matches every line, including empty lines, since it says "all lines that have a start". So you're abusing `grep`s ability to show numbers of matching lines to get a line number in front of every line.

The sed part is rather standard - match a pattern, replace it, put some part of the matched pattern (the number) into the replacement text.

(I hope omitting pizza from the output is a copy/paste error; if not, you'll have to adjust the pattern to grep accordingly, like `grep -n -v pizza file`.

Comment: yes it is an error, thanks for catching that for me! also, would sed just increment the number for me? or do i have to change the number each time?

Comment: It's grep that increments the number, not sed. Try running the first part only. sed just takes the row number that grep produces, and surrounds it with the text you require.

Answer (score 1):

```
index=1
for i in `cat ~/myFile`; do
   echo "Enter $index for: $i"
   index=$((index+1))
done
```

Very simple way. The parameter "index", it is your counter, and you are printing all the file content, line by line.
For each line, you need to increase the counter.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{print "Enter "NR" for: "$0}' filename
Enter 1 for: coffee
Enter 2 for: soda
Enter 3 for: pizza
Enter 4 for: hamburger
Enter 5 for: fries
```